# Tailwind table not resizing properly in a responsive layout

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm facing a layout issue with my Tailwind CSS project, specifically with a table in the main panel. My page layout consists of three primary sections: a sidebar on the left, a top header, and a main panel to the right that contains the table in question.

[image: Full-size page]

I've designed the sidebar to collapse when the browser window is resized horizontally. However, the table in the main panel does not adapt correctly to the resizing. If the table contains text that is longer than the available space, the table overflows, extending off the edge of the page rather than resizing or wrapping the text appropriately.

[image: When shrinking the page, the table goes off the page]

I've been struggling to identify the root cause of this issue and would appreciate any insights or suggestions!

Here is the Tailwind play link for a live demo of the problem: [Tailwind Play Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/K5xKct87nw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `whitespace-nowrap` class added to the table cells. I have modified it to only apply to large screens. On line 201 for example, you can have

```
<td class="lg:whitespace-nowrap py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm sm:pl-6">
```

You can see a demo of your code working well with responsiveness on my [fork of your CDN](https://play.tailwindcss.com/smZUrsqMy0?size=540x720)

Hope this helps. Cheers :)